# Post Tracking number in bigcommerce

Tags: jackson, bigcommerce

I am using jackson API for converting Java to JSON and vice-versa. In bigcommerce there is a API for creating shipment https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders/shipments#create-a-shipment
I have order_id only from the user. So how to create the shipment using POJO?

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code to get you started.

```
public class Shipment {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public long id;

    @JsonProperty("order_id")
    public long orderId;

    @JsonProperty("date_created")
    public String dateCreated;

    @JsonProperty("customer_id")
    public long customerId;

    @JsonProperty("billing_address")
    public Address billingAddress;

    @JsonProperty("shipping_address")
    public Address shippingAddress;
}

public class Address {

    @JsonProperty("zip")
    public String zip;

    @JsonProperty("city")
    public String city;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    public String email;

    @JsonProperty("phone")
    public String phone;

    @JsonProperty("state")
    public String state;

    @JsonProperty("company")
    public String company;

    @JsonProperty("country")
    public String country;

    @JsonProperty("street_1")
    public String street1;

    @JsonProperty("street_2")
    public String street2;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("country_iso2")
    public String countryIso2;
}

public class Application {
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
        // deserialize from JSON string
        Shipment shipment = objectMapper.readValue(someJsonString, Shipment);
        ...
        // serialize to JSON string
        String someJsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(shipment);
        ...
    }
}
```